# c# itext adding text on existing or new pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to create a pdf and add text or load a pdf and overwrite the loaded pdf.
I have some trouble with x and y axis, how do I calculate them or use them.
e.g. I want to put the tekst on 50 points or 3 cm from the left (x) and 10 cm or (?? points) from above (Y).
My code until now below, the second thing is, how can I use a memory stream to load the pdf, change it and overwrite the loaded pdf.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CreateChangePdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"c:\data\pdftest.pdf";
            string TextToAdd = @"New text";
            float x_coordinaat = 50;        // how to get e.g. cm or points to determen x and Y position
            float y_coordinaat = 200;       // how to get e.g. cm or points to determen x and Y position

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                // open a pdf document and add text.
                // overwrite opened file
            }
            else
            {
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                var output = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
                doc.Open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
                // How do I get e.g. x-axis of 10 point and Y axis of 30 point 
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Phrase(new Chunk(TextToAdd, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.NORMAL))),
                              x_coordinaat, y_coordinaat, 10, 10, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                ct.Go();
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question. Split the positioning question and the load/overwrite question into two stackoverflow questions.

Comment: I agree with @MarkusEgle because all the questions you're asking have been answered before on Stack Overflow, but if we close your question as a duplicate of one of those questions, you'll complain that the referred duplicate doesn't help you. Also: it's always a good idea to read [the official documentation](https://developers.itextpdf.com) before asking a question. Finally: you're using an old iText version. Please upgrade to iText 7!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i cant upgade to version 7 because of the license agreement. It had to be fully opensource.

after what time I found an option to get the measurements from the page. 
Now I can use this to calculate the positions.

Comment: iText 7 is just as open source as iText 5. Or do you by chance mean an antique 4.x version? (Which by the way also is just as open source as the newer versions, merely for use under a different license. )